# execute sensor events in android through adb or monkey tool

Tags: android, adb, android-sensors, monkey

Is there any command to perform sensor event in device using monkey or adb like using monkey we can perform so many commands for touch long press etc.but i am not getting any sensor commands

Does anyone have idea about this please share.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can inject events using `adb shell sendevent` command. Name of the device to send the events to is going to be device specific (actually it could change with software upgrade on the same hardware). You can get a list of the devices with `getevent -il`

Another option would be to use some low-level development tool to send `I2C` messages (most sensors sit on I2C bus).

The problem is that while you can inject the extra events - it would not stop the actual sensor from sending its own. So your fake sensor reading would only last till the next real update.